# function to directly open a popup

Tags: javascript, html

I am using greapesjs, I made a block that can be dragged and dropped which duplicate the block and instantly execute its functions. I want a function that directly shows a div without the need to be called by a button.

```
  editor.BlockManager.add('Text', {
        label: 'Text',
        attributes: {
            class: 'fa fa-text'
        },
        content: {
            content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
            script: function show() {
                document.getElementById('foo').style.display = "block";// I want the function to be here, I have tried this but no result

            },
            style: {
                'background-color': 'grey',

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: when u are calling document.getElementById("foo") are u getting div or null?

Comment: I had a template in a div with the id="foo" and I want it to be displayed as a popup.